# Deviation in compressibility factor in different gases

Tags: physical-chemistry

Why does the compressibility factor of gases like Carbon Dioxide and Nitrogen first decrease then increase with increase in pressure , but for Hydrogen and Helium it only increases with the increase in pressure ?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46824/why-do-some-gases-have-lower-value-of-z-for-a-particular-pressure/46982#46982), which addresses this question almost exactly. The only thing to add is the same reasoning I applied for $\ce{H2}$ also applies to helium. Note that for both molecules there is actually a minimum, but they are extremely tiny and not observable on the scale of the plots you're referring to.